# Convert a pen USB to External Hard disk

Tags: ext3

My sat decoder need to have an external HDD to record videos... If I use my 8GB as pen, it doesn't recognize it! How can I convert to it, to let the decoder work?

It has to be partitioned as ext3.

I found  HDD Low Level Format Tool for windows, it should work, but I can't part it in ext3 using it!

Answer (score 1):

Using **gparted** you can do two **primary partitions**, one in ext3, the other one in **fat32**.

I didn't think that you can use an ext3 partition in this purpoise...

bye

Answer (score 0):

as you said abt the tool its for windows and windows doesn't support ext3 so that option will not be available.

i am not sure for ext3 but you can convert it to ext2 and ext4 by simply formating it with suitable option selected in Ubuntu itself ...... hope this will do !!!

Comment: the problem is that the decoder recognizes the pen ( obviously ) as a pen, and the decoder doesn't record with it, it works only with an hardware he recognizes as an external HDD. That software ( only for windows ) can let the pen be recognized as an HDD, but can format the pen only as Fat or ntfs.

Comment: if u are on 11.10 try this :-
dash-->disk utility-->select ur pendrive --->select format volume--> select type ext3 .
i think it shld do !!